# Finding root cause of high software interrupt percentage on a cloud instance

Tags: top

I have a cloud instance that's showing a weird load pattern when checked with top:

```
top - 21:39:28 up 456 days,  8:39,  2 users,  load average: 1.44, 1.19, 1.10
Tasks: 100 total,   1 running,  99 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie             
%Cpu(s):  5.2 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 57.5 id,  1.7 wa,  0.0 hi, 34.9 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16134024 total,   160756 free,  3009108 used, 12964160 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 12620768 avail Mem
```

As can be seen from the header above, the `SI` (software interrupts) percentage is at 35%.

Checking `/proc/interrupts` for software interrupts gives me the possible culprit as `Rescheduling interrupts` which jumped by ~20K over a 60 second duration.

Where I am now stuck is trying to figure out which process/processes are leading to this level of rescheduling.

How do ***I** figure out* the root cause *without touching the running services*?

Additional info:

- Debian 9 (stretch) on a 2 vCPU, 16G mem KVM based cloud instance on AWS.
- `Linux ip-10-0-0-138 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- The instance has `nginx` and `varnish` running as LB for other services.

**Edit:**
One of the other Ops restarted the instance before I could figure out the root cause. After the restart, for the same load, the `%SI` hasn't crossed 1.5%, and the `Rescheduling interrupts` for a 60 second duration fell to less than a third of the previous values.

Answer (score 3):

> ~20K over a 60 second duration.

That's not that many; it's less 400 per second, and would be in the order of magnitude of what I'd expect of a machine where multiple cores are sleeping and there's periodic work to be done, so these get woken up regularly.

However, you're probably not running a live audio system (like jack) on your 2-core (probably more: 1 CPU core with 2 hypethreads) server. And, you only have one core that could be sleeping.

> Debian 9 (stretch) on a 2 vCPU, 16G mem KVM based cloud instance on AWS.

aha!

Compare the comment in the source code of the actual interrupt handler [in your kernel version](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.88/source/arch/x86/kernel/smp.c#L287):

> ```
> /*
>  * KVM uses this interrupt to force a cpu out of guest mode
>  */
> ```

In other words, there might simply be nothing wrong with your VM or your software, it's just the KVM hypervisor wanting to switch one of the CPU cores currently used by your VM to do something else.

Presumably, that's because you're light on load, and amazon figures that they can sell the same CPU time to more users, as you wouldn't expect the full performance of a continously-owned CPU core.

Do an experiment: run `stress -c 2` and see whether having a high load (undubitably bad for your payload performance) reduces your Reschedule Interrupt count significantly.

However, what you'll get will have little practical effect: I doubt aws will reward wasteful machines with more performance, so the question becomes whether these rescheduling interrupts aren't just acceptable – they should probably mainly happen when you're only exploiting less than half of your two CPU threads.

Comment: Interesting! But that could also just mean that AWS used your reboot to move your VM to a different node.

Comment: It seems that I have made multiple errors when reviewing my information in response to your answer, leading to multiple erroneous edits and comments. The question is now in a correctly updated state.